# I need to subtract a mySQL timestamp with a PHP timestamp. Getting a "date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, array given" error

Tags: php, mysql, date

I feel like this should be easy but I have been stuck so long that I am looking for some help from my stackoverflow friends. All I want to do is grab a current timestamp from my mySQL table and subtract it from a current php server timestamp. The mySQL format is

chat_time timestamp current_timestamp()

It looks like this when the insert is completed

2020-06-22 14:51:41

So in my php code I wrote this

```
//chat countdown logic
$curDate = getdate();
$mysqlTimestamp = $row['chat_time'];

$dif=date_diff($curDate,$mysqlTimestamp);

$row['chat_time'] = $dif;
//end of chat countdown logic
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong??

Comment: What do you get when you start `var_dump()`'ing / echoing stuff? What results are you getting as opposed to desired results? What values are in the database?

Comment: `getdate()` is returning an array, not a DateTime object.

Comment: Did you check the manual? https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks, I think I was overlooking the new DateTime() ... I have it sort of working with   $dteStart = new DateTime($row['chat_time']);

Comment: Welcome @CJBroersma glad to see you came up with your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I ended up figuring it out with the advice of the above users.

```
$dteStart = new DateTime($row['chat_time']);
$dteEnd   = new DateTime("now");

$dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);

$row['chat_time'] = $dteDiff->format("%H:%I:%S");
```

Creating the new DateTime() was the key to sync up the database and php dates in order to use the diff() function.

Answer (score 1):

`date_diff()` does not accept 2 dates as strings

> [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

So you will have to convert the strings to DateTime object first

```
// date time now
$curDate = new DateTime();      

// make a datetime object from a timestamp
$mysqlTimestamp = (new DateTime)->setTimestamp($row['chat_time']);

$diff = date_diff($curDate, $mysqlTimestamp);
$print_r($diff);    // see what you get
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I am getting a "A non well formed numeric value encountered " error on the $mysqlTimestamp = (new DateTime)->setTimestamp($row['chat_time']);

Comment: Can you show what is actually in `$row['chat_time']` Do a `var_dump($row['chat_time']);` and post the result please